# Can i send data into webview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, delegates

i have created webview in my app,

```
 NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SimpleCall" ofType:@"html"];

 NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

 [webview loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL: [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];

 [self.view addSubview:webview];
```

now i want to send a data to webview when webview starts load.is there any property for uiwebview?

thanks advance.

Comment: What data? Please elaborate, your question is unclear.

Comment: GET and POST data?

Answer (score 0):

you must set the delegate `UIWebViewDelegate` property on your `UIWebView`, for example:

```
webView.delegate = self;
```

where `self` conforms to `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol and implement callback method `webViewDidStartLoad` (check [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebviewdelegate)) if you really want to do something when web view starts load. Then, you implement the method:

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
 //you can do something in here, but DON'T call any loaders of webView's - loadHTML or reload, cause this will result in a loop
}
```

But I doubt that will solve your problem - first of all you probably want to do something when web view finishes. Second - can you elaborate more on what you mean by:

> send data to web view

DISCLAIMER: as of iOS 8 and higher you should use `WKWebView` instead.

EDIT: as clarified in comments you want to update dynamically html contents. In `WKWebView` [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview?language=objc) you can read that there is no option to do that (i.e. dynamically insert options from your NSArray to loaded html string). You have to manually update your html string and then reload `WKWebView` with new, updated html. Reloading whole html just to update one feature is probably not an option here, so better store the webpage loaded on the server and update dynamically (when web page is updated with new options) by calling:

```
[webView reload];
```

Comment: i have one html file which is downled from every time when i am login or refresh a data in app.now before load webview i need to send a NSArray to html for dropdown(html)values. Array is dynamic.

Comment: @KrishSolanki I updated my answer according to what you provided, but what you trying to accomplish is not achievable on the "device" side.